# Como convertir un float angulo a Vector2 y viceversa en Unity ::: Vector2 (0,1) == 90°

Tags: c#, unity, matemáticas, c#-8.0

En mi proyecto necesito convertir un float(angulo trigonométrico) en un vector2. busque en Internet como convertir un vector2 a float pero solo me aparecían problemas de errores muy básicos, al principio pensé que Vector2.Ang(vector1,vector2) devolvía en angulo pero en realidad devuelve la diferencia lo cual no me sirve.

Una opción fácil seria utilizar la variable **rotación** de component **transform**:

```
 public static class Extension : MonoBeha...no_me_recuerdo :v{
    
    // utilizando la rotacion(Quaternion) de transform

    // de un vector2 a float
    public static float VectorToFloat(Vector2 _Vector){
        instanciate.transform.up = _Vector.normalized;
        return instanciate.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
    }

   // de un float a vector
   public static Vector2 FloatToVector(float ang){
        instanciate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,ang);
        return instanciate.transform.up;
    }
}
```

Pero ¡Y si no puedo utilizar Transform?
Con mi limitada sabiduría logre **convertir de vector2 a un float angulo sin Transform** apoyándome en Vector2.Ang() de Unity, incluso le añadí una variable que controla de donde la dirección de angulo(lo cual me hace sentir orgulloso :v)

```
 // de vector a float sin transform
 public static float GetAng(this Vector2 _my_vector,bool spin_clock = true){
    _my_vector = _my_vector.normalized;
    float ang = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.up,_my_vector);
    if(ang == 0 || ang == 180) return ang;
    float dis = 180 - ang;
    if(spin_clock)  if(_my_vector.x < 0) ang += dis*2;
    else            if(_my_vector.x > 0) ang += dis*2;
    return ang;
}
```

pero ahora quiero **convertir de float a Vector2**, mi cerebro de chango intento utilizar una función parabólica que hice hace unas semanas
(Si quieres léelo pero **funciona ligeramente mal**(lo que también no me sirve))

```
//  FloatToVector2 fallido 
public static class Extension_Fallida{
  public static Vector2 FloatToVector2(this float num){
    while (0 > num){num += 360;} 
    while (360 < num){num -= 360;} 

    float _Y = 0;
    float _X = 0;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    if(90 > num){
        if(num == 0) return Vector2.up;
        _X = num.Normalized(0,90);
        _Y = num.Normalized(0,90) + 1;
        x = _X.Fun_Parabola();
        y = _Y.Fun_Parabola();      
    }
    else if(180 > num){
        if(num == 90) return Vector2.right;
        _X = num.Normalized(90,180) + 1;
        _Y = num.Normalized(90,180) + 1;
        x = _X.Fun_Parabola();
        y = _Y.Fun_Parabola()-1;  
    }
    else if(270 > num){
        if(num == 180) return -Vector2.up;
        _X = num.Normalized(180,270) + 1;
        _Y = num.Normalized(180,270);
        x = _X.Fun_Parabola()-1;
        y = _Y.Fun_Parabola()-1;   
    }
    else{
        if(num == 270) return -Vector2.right;
        _X = num.Normalized(270,360);
        _Y = num.Normalized(270,360);
        x = _X.Fun_Parabola()-1;
        y = _Y.Fun_Parabola();    
    }
    return new Vector2(x,y);
  }

// 0.5f de 7.Normalized(4,10)
// comvierte num a un float 0 a 1 de entre min y max
public static float Normalized(this float num,float min,float max){
    float dif = max - min;
    while(num > max){num -= dif;}
    while(num < min){num += dif;}

    float par = num-min;
    return par / dif;
}

  public static float Fun_Parabola(this float numero){
    // 0 al 2
    if(numero > 2) while(numero > 2){numero -= 2;}
    if(numero < 0) while(numero < 0){numero += 2;}
    float punto = -Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs(numero-1)) + 1; 
    return punto;
  }
}
```

**¿Que funciona mal en esta función?** Si es que lo probaste haciéndolo rotar un transform constantemente.
(tranform.up = FloatToVector2(ang++)) cada Frame se habrá dado cuenta de que el giro devuelve el vector2 **bien en ángulos 0,90,180,360** **pero** en los demás **ligeramente desfasados o errados**, **especialmente cuando mas lejos de estos ángulos esta**.

**:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:***

Ahora si, aquí va mi pedido de auxilio...
**¿Como puedo convertir vector2 a float y viceversa?** pero con **puras matemáticas** para implementarlo en otros proyectos con diferentes lenguajes.

Answer (score 1):

Un vector no representa un ángulo, por lo que no puedes transformar un vector a un float.
Lo que pretendes realizar tú es calcular el ángulo que existe entre el vector (0,1) y la horizontal (eje X).
Por lo tanto, ¿cómo puedes calcular ese ángulo que buscas?

1. Crea un vector referencia que represente el eje X positivo (Vector2(1,0)).
2. Con la función Vector2.Angle() calcula el ángulo entre el vector de referencia y el vector de entrada.
3. Por último, para diferenciar por ejemplo 90º y 270º de rotación, tendrás que mirar si el valor del eje 'y' del vector de entrada (si es positivo, el ángulo estará entre 0º y 180º, si es negativo, el ángulo estará entre 180º y 360º)

Prueba a ejecutar este código:

```
    Vector2 referencia = new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f);
    Vector2 noventa_grados = new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f);
    Vector2 doscientos_setenta_grados = new Vector2(0.0f, -1.0f);
    float grados1 = Vector2.Angle(referencia, noventa_grados);
    float grados2 = Vector2.Angle(referencia, doscientos_setenta_grados);

    if (noventa_grados.y < 0)
        print(360f - grados1);
    else
        print(grados1);


    if (doscientos_setenta_grados.y < 0)
        print(360f - grados2);
    else
        print(grados2);
```

EDIT:

Para el método inverso, un ángulo lo puedes pasar a vector con el resultado seno y coseno. Eso sí, el ángulo tendrá que estar transformado [de grados a radianes](https://ekuatio.com/como-pasar-de-grados-a-radianes-y-de-radianes-a-grados/):

```
    Vector2 resultado = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angulo_en_radianes), Mathf.Sin(angulo_en_radianes));
```